# Collision Detection in 2D Motion

Tags: c, physics

I have created a very simple numerical simulation that models an object being thrown off a building at some angle, and when the object hits the ground, the simulation stops. Now I want to add in collision detection. How would I go about doing this? 
I know I need to find the exact time that the object (a ball) hits the ground, as well as the velocity in the x and y direction, and position of the object when it hits the ground, and I have to add in parameters that say how much the ball will bounce on impact. But I don't know how to go about doing this. I know that there are various ways of detecting collision but since I am new to this, the most comprehensible method would be best.

Comment: [Wham!](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3015/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php) (That link demonstrates a fast, accurate and "easy" method to detect collisions.)

Comment: Sounds like 2D, not 1D, motion.

Comment: There are simple formulas for finding out all this information, unless you're *required* to simulate it, you should probably just look into them. Stat by calculating the [velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity) and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make a coordinate system, with the ground at y=0. Track the coordinates of the ball as it flies and then check when it has y=0, and that's where it hits the ground. You can also keep track of the x and y velocity as the ball is moving.
- Use Physics skillz. [This](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/traj.html) is a good tutorial. If you have it, I recommend Fundamentals of Physics by Halliday, Resnick and Walker. They have a very good chapter on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for the math, that you could write C code for. I found this one helpful. [Math Models](http://www.edenwaith.com/products/pige/tutorials/collision.php)

Answer (score 0):

Collision detection simply involves determining the distance between 2 objects.

If you are only interested in collisions between objects and the ground, you can use:

```
if(object.y <= ground.y) {
    //collision occurred
}
```

To do collisions between objects, you can loop through all objects and compare them to each other in the same way.

Comment: What I don't understand though is how to implement the actual collision. What do I do when a collision occurs?

Comment: @kachilous You can absorb the energy so that the object sticks splat on the ground. You can make the object "bounce" at half the speed it was coming on at the ground. There is no right answer to that question - it depends on how complex you want to make it (a world-class physics engine!), how fast (for real-time rendering as in games), and how much precious time of your life you're willing to waste doing it. (There's "free" super-awesome physics engines available - Havok, Bullet, etc.)